# Erro ao executar studio.sh

Tags: linux, android-studio

Olá, sou novo em desenvolvimento com Java.

Estou usando o fedora 26 e o openjdk java version "1.8.0_91".

minhas variáveis de ambiente estão:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/
export MANPATH=$JAVA_HOME/man
export STUDIO_JDK=/opt/android-studio/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$CLASSPATH:$STUDIO_JDK
```

quando executo o studio.sh dá o erro a seguir

> JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
>   Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

falta alguma coisa para rodar o android studio para linux?

Answer (score 1):

Confira se realmente seu JDK está instalado corretamente com

```
dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

Se não estiver, reinstale. Em seguida, habilite seu JDK:

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

Confira a versão instalada com:

```
java -version
```

Se estiver tudo certo, o retorno será algo parecido com isso aqui:

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Depois confira o compilador com:

```
javac -version
```

Se estiver tudo certo, o retorno será algo parecido com isso aqui:

```
javac 1.8.0_91
```

Por fim, adicione `JAVA_HOME` ao seu `$PATH`
Edite seu `/etc/environment` e adicione `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` (ou compátivel com o Java que baixou) no final do arquivo.

Você vai ter que reiniciar tua máquina depois de editar `$PATH`, dá pra fazer pelo terminal mesmo, com:

```
sudo reboot
```